# Search Oracle date type column with hibernate, search by everything in that day - ignore the time

Tags: database, oracle, hibernate, datetime

batch create date

table column type is

```
BATCH_CREATED_DATE  DATE            NOT NULL
```

With the data in that date column being similar to this '2010-05-13 14:56:36.0'

now I want to search for all items within the 24 hours of 2010-05-13, currently my call only returns all items with date "2010-05-13 14:56:36.0" exactly.

What would my HQL statement look like to hand this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the parameters you're going to pass, I can think of several solutions:

- With `'2010-05-13 00:00:00.0'` and `'2010-05-13 23:59:59.9'`:

  ```
  from MyEntity e where e.date between :startDate and :endDate
  ```
- With `'2010-05-13 00:00:00.0'` and `'2010-05-14 00:00:00.0'`:

  ```
  from MyEntity e where :startDate <= e.date and e.date < :endDate
  ```
- With `'2010-05-13 XX:XX:XX.X'`:

  ```
  from MyEntity e where year(e.date)  = year(:aDate) 
                    and month(e.date) = month(:aDate)
                    and day(e.date)   = day(:aDate)
  ```

Comment: I also found that your last example works a treat with joda DateTime().getYear(), getMonthOfYear() and getDayOfMonth() functions. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This could be useful.
[Using HQL to query on a date while ignoring the time on Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980366/using-hql-to-query-on-a-date-while-ignoring-the-time-on-oracle)