# Hibernate - how to query date without time

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to query an exact date without time, is there a way to do this? Example, return all records that have the date `2013-11-06`.

I've tried the following, but I think it's failing do to the time piece of the date.

```
//Preset calendar date. 
Date searchDate = obj.searchDate();

session.criteriaQuery(TimeSheet.class).add(Restrictions.eq("createDate", searchDate )).list();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using HQL to query on a date while ignoring the time on Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980366/using-hql-to-query-on-a-date-while-ignoring-the-time-on-oracle)

Comment: @OldProgrammer I assumed that was going to be the only way to handle this. I guess I was hoping for something simpler. Thanks.