# Hibernate HQL: Convert Datetime to Date?

Tags: hibernate, datetime, hql

On a SELECT query i want to convert my DATETIME column to DATE format (taking only year, month and day).

I was using DATE construct: DATE(table.column) and it was great but it seems that this construct doesen't works on SQLSERVER databases (i was working on MySql previously).

This is the error i met:

```
 data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.MethodNode +-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '(' | +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'DATE'
```

Someone can help me fix this? I tried using CONVERT and CAST but i met same error.

This is the query:

```
SELECT DATE(al.loginTime) as loginTime, (COUNT(al.hawkUser)) as numeroAccessi, al.hawkUser as hawkUser, al.logoutTime as logoutTime " +
                "FROM AccessLog as al GROUP BY al.hawkUser, DATE(al.loginTime) ORDER BY DATE(al.loginTime) DESC, al.hawkUser DESC
```

Comment: is this a projection? add the query please

Comment: It seems that you are using native sql instead of HQL. what is the format of column in database.is it datetime?Please add some more details.

Comment: I added the complete query.

Comment: Try the solution using between in HQL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/980406/1934211

Comment: I see it as native query and not as HQL.have you tried executing query in database u can replace variable with any values.If that works ,query is correct ,but this is native query not HQL.hibernate gives you provision to run native query also.

Comment: .Can you print the full stack trace of exception

Answer (score 0):

Ok i modified several times the query, now is like this:

```
 String query="SELECT "
        + "  al.loginTime as loginTime,"
        + " (COUNT(hu.id)) as numeroAccessi, "
        + " hu.id as hawkUser "
                + "FROM AccessLog as al "
                + " INNER JOIN al.hawkUser hu "
                + " GROUP BY "
                + " al.loginTime,"
                + " hu.id "
                + " ORDER BY "
                + " al.loginTime DESC"
                + " hu.email  ";
```

loginTime is DATETIME with hours, minuted and seconds while i need to regroup them only using year month and day (it's a login list). So i still have to convert DATETIME to DATE. I can't use CAST and CONVERT since this query is for MySql and SQLServer database and the syntax is different for both.